# JHipster registry /encrypt and /decrypt endpoints missing

Tags: jhipster, spring-cloud-config, jhipster-registry

I am using latest JHipster Registry updated just couple of days ago. I am trying to setup `symmetric key encryption` that is part of spring boot itself https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html (see Key Management). I have gotten it to work in Spring boot by setting the key in `bootstrap.properties`

Under JHipster, the developers advise is that all endpoints are under `/management/**` so I have tried `/management/encrypt` and just `encrypt` both return a 404.

I have set the `encrypt.key` in many places to try and get this to work

1. environment variable `ENCRYPT_KEY`
2. in git under application.yml
3. in bootstrap.yml within the registry app

However it still does not activate the endpoints or something else is wrong. If anyone has gotten it to work please indicate if it works for you and what settings you used.

Comment: Have you tried to set logging level to DEBUG for Spring to see all request mappings listed?

Comment: I should probably have tried that because the startup process in Jhipster does not show any endpoints as you would normally expect in Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JHipster Registry sets a prefix for the config server endpoints to be served under `/config`, this property is set in the `bootstrap.yml` and `bootstrap-prod.yml` files.

Once you add the encrypt.key property (or ENCRYPT_KEY environment variable) and install the "Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files" according to the [Spring Cloud Config docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_encryption_and_decryption), you can access the encrypt/decrypt endpoints at:

http://admin:password@registry:8761/config/encrypt
http://admin:password@registry:8761/config/decrypt